# How to pass Parameters to Partials and Components?

Tags: symfony1

I'm pretty new to the Symfony Framework and currently searching for the Best-Practice way to pass Parameters from a search to the included partials.

Currently I'm checking for the Parameter in the executeSearch Method and then setting a variable that is available in the `searchSuccess.php` File.

In the searchSuccess.php File I'm simply passing the variable to the Partial in the `include_partial` Method in the array. I keep passing the variable around until I'm in the correct partial.

My Method seems to complicated and wrong, but it seems I can't access the sfRequest variables outside the `executeSearch` Method?

Comment: You can access the request in any template by calling `$sf_request`.

Comment: @j0k : you're right, so why not write an answer?

Comment: @greg0ire : I was not sure about the question, that's why I only post a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the request object in any template by calling `$sf_request`.